# how to get dictionary value in python from dynamic key

Tags: python

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('trial.xls')
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)

name_email={}

i=0
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
    if name_email.has_key(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value):
         name_email[str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value.strip())]=sheet.cell(row_index,i+1).value,)
    else:              
        abc = str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value.strip())
        print repr(abc)
        print '"{0}"'.format(repr(abc))
        # print name_email[abc]
        name_email[str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value.strip())]=sheet.cell(row_index,i+1).value
i+=1            
print name_email.keys()
print name_email
```

The out put is :
    'manoj'
    "'manoj'"
    'dibyendu'
    "'dibyendu'"
    'sourav'
    "'sourav'"
    ['dibyendu', 'sourav', 'manoj']
    {'dibyendu': (u'd.b@gmail.com',), 'sourav': (u's.b@gmail.com',), 'manoj': (u'm.c@gmail.com',)}

But still cant access print name_email[abc] throwing the error 
    print name_email[abc]
    KeyError: 'manoj'

Comment: There may be leading or trailing whitespace, try `abc = str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value.strip())`.  If this still doesn't work, please add `print repr(abc)` before you attempt the dictionary access and edit your question with the output.

Comment: What does `repr(abc)` print? What does `print name_email.keys()` tell you is in the dictionary?

Comment: Better still, `print '"{0}"'.format(repr(abc))`

Comment: I have modified the code and printed the same you asked to. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem lies not in the variable used as an index (which is just fine, and works as one could expect), but in your if condition.

Your code

```
if name_email.has_key(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value):
    name_email[str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value)]=(sheet.cell(row_index,i+1).value,)
else:
    #print name_email[str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value)]

    abc= str(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value)
    print name_email[abc]
```

tries to print `name_email[abc]` if and only if `name_mail` **does not contain** the `abc` key (as it is in the "else:" sstatement. It seems like you wanted to do exactly the opposite - print it when it **has** a key, and **add** when it does not, right? Simply rearrange your if condition.

now it is something like

```
if x.has_key(y):
    x[y] = 1
else:
    print x[y]
```

while it should be

```
if x.has_key(y):
    print x[y]
else:
    x[y] = 1
```

Comment: Perfect it make perfect sense, I have written foolish logic. Thanks @lejlot

Comment: glad I could help. Remember to mark the correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 3):

It works just as you'd think:

```
>>> mydict = {"spam": "flat", "eggs": "round"}
>>> print mydict["eggs"]
round
>>> mykey = "eggs"
>>> print mydict[mykey]
round
>>>
```

Your variable `abc` obviously isn't containing what you think it is, if it works when you hardcode the key.